S3 bucket unable to serve react webapp because of react-router-dom
I am building a webapp using react as my frontend. I have deployed an EC2 instance on AWS, installed nginx and configured proxy_pass to serve the app files including the index.html on a S3 bucket. I used gitlab's CI/CD to automate the build and deploy it to S3 bucket. But S3 is not able to serve my index.html and signin page when I access my domain. However, if I build the app and upload it to my EC2 instance, the web app runs absolutely fine and is able to route to any page on the website. So I wanted to know why S3 hates react-router-dom. I understand that react is a single page website and that routing is done on the client side to other pages of the website. But why is S3 is not able to use the index.html as entry point every time there is a request for a page other than the index.html. I have configured index.html as error page under bucket web hosting properties.
I have tried to set the correct bucket permissions, properties but it is not displaying my web page when I access my domain, it just displays a blank page. When I access the index.html file from the bucket, it displays only the footer which is outside the routes.
app.js:
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignIn from './SignIn';

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={
              <div className="content">
                <img src="/logo.png" alt="Logo" className="logo" />
                <h1>Website Under Construction</h1>
                <p>We're working hard to bring you a great experience. Stay tuned!</p>
              </div>
            } />
            <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
          </Routes>
          <footer className="footer">
            <p>&copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} . All rights reserved.</p>
          </footer>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}
export default App;



Can you please share the view of chrome devlopper console while loading the website (blank page) ?

Hi, thank you for trying to assist me. But I took a different approach now. So I moved my webapp to my EC2 instance for now. I apologise. Thank you for your time.
